How to deploy a PostgreSQL database for Flask App on Vercel?
I deployed my Flask App on Vercel.
But I can't find any StakOverflow answers or YouTube tutorials on how to connect my PostgreSQL  database to the app on Vercel.
I am reading the documentation but it seems it's only possible for node.js applications.
CAN WE DEPLOY A FLASK APP ON VERCEL??
This is my complete github repository
https://github.com/ELentiya-001/Blog_Website
What I have done already

I have deployed my app and added the required env variables
I have created the PostgreSQL database on Vercel

Specifically my problem
How to connect the created SQLite database to the app

Connecting Flask to Vercel's PostgreSQL using SQLAlchemy is  straightforward. Vercel's PostgreSQL uses Neon DB so the setup is the same,  you just need a connection string and SQLAlchemy.
Go to your project settings and copy the connection string without the psql

Here is a simple demo:
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# Initialize Flask app and set connection string from Vercel's dashboard
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "<paste_your_postgresql_connection_string_here>"
# Initialize SQLAlchemy and defining a simple Book model
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Book(db.Model):
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)

# Create database tables in the PostgreSQL database
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

One more thing, to avoid SQL Alchemy dialect error as in this stackoverflow question
The URI should start with postgresql:// instead of postgres://.
SQLAlchemy used to accept both, but has removed support for the postgres name. #1st answer that worked.
Also consider using environment variables for your app security.
Refer to this documentation to setup serverless postgresql:
https://neon.tech/docs/connect/connect-from-any-app
